# check for number anywhere in a string

Tags: php

```
$vari = "testing 245";
$numb = 0..9;

$numb_pos =  strpos($vari,$numb);
echo substr($vari,0,$numb_pos);
```

The $numb is numbers from 0 to 9
Where am I wrong here, all I need to echo is testing

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in here?

Comment: Yes I need to echo the word testing only eliminating the number.  The number is always at the end of the word

Answer (score 5):

You want to cut out the numbers from a string?

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '', 'String with 1234 numbers');
```

Comment: The (\d+) part gets all the numbers from the string provided and replaces them with the second parameter - in this case, with nothing.

Comment: This is the way to go. Your psudo code fails to work is because PHP doesn't take 0..9 style, you can do foreach(range(0..9) as $numb) {} instead

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work as-is, as it'll fail if the number if the first character in the string. (You need to check $numb_pos !== false prior to the substr.)

Irrespective, if you just want to check for the existance of a number in a string, something like the following would probably be more efficient.

```
$digitMatched = preg_match('/\\d/im', $vari);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to strip numeric characters from your string.

or, use a regular expression to find the first instance of one either way...

Comment: robertbasic provided details.